# how to rise event when you click on a gridview row, without selectButton?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, webforms

I can´t find anything like onrowclick or onclick event, is possible to fire event when you click on gridview row?

Comment: what kind of event you'd like to raise ?

Comment: I want to raise onclick like event

Comment: Try [`this link`](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/50080/Extended-ASP-NET-GridView-with-cell-click-events) ..

Comment: Thanks i was finding something like that. Is free for commercial use?

Comment: As you see in the bottom .. **This article, along with any associated source code and files, is licensed under The Code Project Open License (CPOL)**

Answer (score 1):

Not using standard ASP.NET control events, since one does not exist for that purpose. Instead, you could use client-side JavaScript to issue an AJAX request, exposing a static `WebMethod` to handle the thing: but, without knowing *why*, this might be absolutely useless.

Answer (score 1):

do this in grid RowDataBound event:

```
if(e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
{
  e.Row.Attributes["onClick"] = "";//any thing you want.
}
```

Comment: with this the event rises when data is loaded into a row, isn´it?